# c++ sequence calculator x_{n+1} = f (x_n), trouble with math functions

Tags: c++

example of code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//whitespace package
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
using std::setw;

int main () {

    // n is an array of 101 integers
    double n[ 101 ];
    double exponent=3;
    double fraction=1/7;

    // initialize elements of array n to 0
    for ( int i = 1; i < 100; i++ ) {
        n[ i ] =  0;
    }

    //what is input 1?
    cout << "Enter x_1" << endl;
    cin >> n[1];

    //jam ni's into function and loop
    for ( int i = 1; i < 100; i++ ) {

        // set element at location i+1 to f(x)= (fraction)*((x)^exponent + 2)
        n[ i + 1 ] =  fraction*(pow( ((n[ i ]) ), exponent ) + 2);
    }

    //header
    cout << "Element" << setw( 13 ) << "Value" << endl;

    // output each array element's value
    for ( int j = 1; j < 100; j++ ) {
        cout << setw( 7 )<< j << setw( 13 ) << n[ j ] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output

```
Enter x_1
1
Element        Value
      1            1
      2            0
      3            0
      4            0
      5            0
      6            0
      7            0
      8            0
      9            0
     10            0
```

....

where my expected output would be

```
Element        Value
      1            1
      2            0.42857142857
      3            0.29695960016
      4            0.2894553405
      5            0.28917883433
      6            0.28916891514
      7            0.28916855966
```

...

background: I'm trying to write a simple program that asks what your \$x_1\$ is and reports \$x_1\$ to \$x_{100}\$ given some series function calculator--like a sequence calculator where \$x_{n+1} = f(x_n)\$. In this example, our function is (1/7)*((x)^3 + 2).

**Can you all offer some resources for writing other functions?** I have \$x_{n+1}=f(x_n)=(1/7)*((x_n^3)+2)\$ right now.

Whenever I look up c++ math functions I get things like how to use the absolute value function, or how to use my cpp file as a function itself, but not information on writing math functions like this.

Comment: I stopped reading your question here _" The program works but is still giving me some kind of weird error."_.  Could you clarify or remove this as erroring and working are usually mutually exclusive.

Comment: This asks for input. What are the input, actual output, and expected output of the [mcve]? Can't you just set those in the code instead of asking me to type it in, since we're only dealing with fixing the problem?

Comment: Well, the compiler does have a point. n[i+1] can be outside the array. It looks like you got confused about whether you were going to skip the first or last.

Comment: @ness Arrays in C++ start at index 0, not 1.  You have a buffer overrun. `n[ i + 1 ] =...`, all probably due to trying to fake 1-based arrays in C++.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is a numeric literal like 7 is assumed to be an integer. That makes 1/7 integer math. No fractions allowed. 1/7 = 0. 1.0/7 forces floating point math, so you'll get an answer more in line with your expectations. [More good reading.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Side note: `pow` can be expensive. It's built to handle really nasty work like e to the power of pi, so stuff like `pow(x,2)` to square `x` can be overkill. Write what's easiest to read, but if you need some speed, you may find it in multiplication.

Comment: @user4581301 how do I use a fraction instead?

Comment: as @user4581301 said 1/7 = 0 because it is interpreted as integer division. To fix this just do ` fraction = 1.0 / 7; `

Answer (score 0):

To report x_1 to x_100 you don't need an array of 101 elements but an array of 100 elements, indexed from 0 inclusive to 100 exclusive. The index of the array is one less than the order of the element of the sequence starting at order 1.

You can use value initialization to set all the elements of the array to 0 in same statement than the declaration.

In C++ the result of division of two integers is an integer, this why your `fraction` number was 0. So to obtain a non-truncated value, one of the operands should be double (the other will be promoted to double by the compiler before the division).

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

constexpr size_t elems_len = 100;

int main()
{
    double n[elems_len]{}; // value initialization, all elements of n are set to 0                                               
    double exponent = 3;

    // one of the operands should be double to avoid integer division and truncation                                             
    double fraction = 1.0 / 7;

    cout << "Enter x_1" << endl;
    cin >> n[0];

    for (size_t i = 1; i < elems_len; i++) {
        n[i] = fraction * (pow(n[i-1], exponent) + 2);
    }

    cout << "Element" << setw(13) << "Value" << endl;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(11);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < elems_len; i++) {
        cout << setw(7) << i + 1 << setw(25) << n[i] << endl;
    }
}
```